# How to retroactively make old files content types?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

Is there a way to make files that are copied into a document library or that already exist in a library a certain content type?

For example, I have various content types based on the Document content type (e.g. contracts, letters, memos, etc.).. This is fine for all new content created by users... but what about old content that already exists in a document library? how do I migrate existing files to be mapped to those content types?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a migration tool like [Sharegate](https://sharegate.com/products/sharegate-desktop) then you can set the content type manually on large groups of documents - either during a migration, or after a migration using the software's Bulk Edit capabilities.

Another option would be to use a SP2013 workflow to set certain content types for items. You could build a simple workflow to loop through all the documents in a library, and based on the criteria for each one, set the content type programmatically:

[image]

PowerShell would be another tool in the arsenal for bulk setting of content type.

Comment: Can you use a SP2013 workflow on SharePoint Online?

Comment: @Ushka yes, you can use SP2013 worfklow in SPO

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PowerShell to fulfill your needs.

You can refer to the article below:

[How do I programatically change the content type of an existing file?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35503/how-do-i-programatically-change-the-content-type-of-an-existing-file)